# How can I repair a puncture in a fiberglass shower floor?

Tags: repair, shower, floor

I have a hole in my shower floor, and I would like to use some sort of resin to cover the hole. Would you recommend me a solution (off the shelves product) that I can use on this hole?

[image]
[image]

Comment: how deep is it?

Comment: It looks "skin deep", @JACK. You can see the unfinished fiberglass below.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer; they were really helpful!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a gap between the finish layer and the structural layer, which was apparently pushed away by the impact. You'll want to re-bond that area with epoxy and fill the hole all at once. Work epoxy well back into the gap, then fill the hole to level.

Just about any two-part epoxy should do. Read labels and find one that claims to bond to fiberglass, etc. Ideally you'll find a white one so you don't have to try and conceal the repair with surface coatings, which may not hold up.

The area will never be as strong as it originally was, so avoid concentrated loads there.

Comment: Might consider adding some small drops of epoxy to the surface as it starts to set up. Waiting until it starts to set will allow the epoxy to remain as drops on the surface, it will (somewhat) mimic the texturing on the rest of the surface, and will provide a modicum of additional traction on that spot (as the texture over the rest of the stall is designed to do).

Comment: I was able to find a Fiberglass repair kit on Amazon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go to a marina store or auto store and get a fiberglass repair kit. Put some coated mesh into the hole and level/smooth it out. I'd then place another piece about two inches in diameter over the entire hole and surrounding area. Sand, smooth out edges and paint with some acrylic paint to match shower. You might not need the patch over the hole if the mesh in the hole is strong enough.

Answer (score 1):

Step one - dry it well - water is going to be in there and water will interfere with the repair.

Either a standard slow-cure epoxy and "microballoons" (aka fumed silica) mixed in to make it a paste/putty or an epoxy putty product would appear to be advisable, as a fully liquid epoxy will apparently not fill the whole defect without running out. The fumed silica also makes the result (with clear epoxy) basically white, though you can overcoat if your epoxy or putty does not end up white.